# how to repeat function in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I made a function in Excel. But after cell update function value is not changed. How to update function cell value after cell changing

```
Public Function SumaByColor(ByVal ColorIndex As Range, ByVal TableRange As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Range
Dim colorIndexNumber As Integer
Dim colorSum As Double

colorIndexNumber = ColorIndex.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each cell In TableRange
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colorIndexNumber Then
colorSum = colorSum + 1
End If

Next cell

SumaByColor = colorSum
End Function
```

Comment: AFAIK, changing the colors in some cells does not trigger calculation. You'll need to force re-calculation using `F9`, or ultimately you can intercept `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

Comment: what have I write in Worksheet_SelectionChange

Comment: `Me.Calculate`, for Example.

Answer (score 1):

First use `Application.Volatile` beginning of codes then write `Me.Calculate` in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

```
Public Function SumaByColor(ByVal ColorIndex As Range, ByVal TableRange As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim colorIndexNumber As Integer
    Dim colorSum As Double

    colorIndexNumber = ColorIndex.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each cell In TableRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colorIndexNumber Then
    colorSum = colorSum + 1
    End If

    Next cell

    SumaByColor = colorSum
End Function
```

***Worksheet_SelectionChange:***
[image]